# how to implement star rating using JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

hello guys here is my doubt about how to get the radio button checked using simple jquery and display the value by its side

for example when the first input tag is checked the star should change it to yellow color :) when unchecked it should change back to its normal color

Please do not suggest to me any plugins

```css
.myratings {
                font-size: 0.875rem;
                color: green;
                position: relative;
                top: 12px;
                margin-left: 9px;
            }
            .rating>[id^="star"] {
                display: none
            }
            .rating>label:before {
                margin-right: 5px;
                font-size: 1.75rem;
                display: inline-block;
                content: "\2605";
                font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
            }
            .rating>.half:before {
                content: "\2605";
                position: absolute;
                width: 10px;
                overflow: hidden;
            }
            .rating>label {
                color: #ddd!important;
                float: right
            }
   
            .rating:not(:checked)>label:hover,
            .rating:not(:checked)>label:hover~label {
                color: #FFD700!important;
            }
            .checked {
                color: #FFD700!important;
            }
            .rating>[id^="star"]:checked+label:hover,
            .rating>[id^="star"]:checked~label:hover,
            .rating>label:hover~[id^="star"]:checked~label,
            .rating>[id^="star"]:checked~label:hover~label {
                color: #FFD700!important;
            }
```

```html
<fieldset class="rating">
                                            <input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" /><label class="full" for="star5" title="Awesome"></label>
                                            <input type="radio" id="star4" name="rating" value="4" /><label class="full" for="star4" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
                                            <input type="radio" id="star3" name="rating" value="3" /><label class="full" for="star3" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
                                            <input type="radio" id="star2" name="rating" value="2" /><label class="full" for="star2" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
                                            <input type="radio" id="star1" name="rating" value="1" /><label class="full" for="star1" title="poor - 1 star"></label>
                                        </fieldset>
<span class="myratings">0</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this problem is to use vanilla javascript to track the currently selected rating and update each label with the appropriate color.

References I used to create this solution:
[setAttribute](https://bl.ocks.org/tzi/2953155#:%7E:text=To%20set%20a%20CSS%20inline%20style%20as%20an,set%20style.%20There%20is%20a%20specific%20syntax%20%3B%29)

```
//The current rating
let currentRating = 0;
//Grab all the label elements and sort them from least to greatest using the last number in the htmlFor string
let labels = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("label")).sort((a, b) => a.htmlFor.substring(4) - +b.htmlFor.substring(4));

//onclick event handler
function clicker(num) {
//If the user clicked on the current rating, set to 0
if (currentRating == num) currentRating = 0;
//Otherwise, set it to the current rating
else currentRating = num;
//Update the text for the current rating
document.querySelector(".myratings").innerHTML = currentRating;

//Loop through all the labels and update their colors
for (let i = 0; i <= 4; i++) { 
  let label=labels[i]; 
  if ((i + 1)> currentRating) label.setAttribute('style', 'color:#ddd !important');
  else label.setAttribute('style', 'color:#FFD700 !important')
}
```